# Is it possible to modify dynamically added DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I have some javascript libraries (for example Adobe Edge), which dynamically insert script nodes into DOM.
I detect changes with MutationsObserver, is it possible to modify the mutated nodes?

Comment: Of course, why not - have you tried it? Only you need to be careful not to get trapped in a mutation event circle.

Comment: It's a shame. I haven't expected that it was really so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can modify nodes that are added to the DOM dynamically just like you can any other node.

```
var target = document.querySelector('div');

new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function (node) {
            node.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        });
    });
}).observe(document.querySelector('div'), {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true});

target.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/rK6Hr/

Answer (score 0):

Calling `takeRecords()` on your MutationObserver should give you an array of MutationRecords, they have property `target` which is the node that has been changed.

Basically check the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).